# Python no such file or directory error trying to print a file list directory on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I am using Udacity trying to learn to code. We are on a lesson that is showing us to locate and rename files. I am currently trying to get the window to print the list of files in the folder by following the file path using this code:

```
import os

def rename_files():
    # (1) get file names from a folder
    list_files = os.listdir("Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨minstrelking⁩ ▸ ⁨Downloads⁩ ▸ ⁨prank⁩⁩")
    print (list_files)

rename_files()
```

I have tried many variations of this such as removing "Macintosh HD" or altering it to "Macintosh_HD". I tried removing folders from the end of the path one by one, and double-checked my spelling constantly. I tried replacing the small arrows ("▸") with forward slashes, then back slashes, and even a recommended combination of the two. I tried adding:

```
os.path.expanduser
```

As recommended on other forums concerning this issue. However, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/minstrelking/Documents/rename_file.py", line 7, in <module>
rename_files()
File "/Users/minstrelking/Documents/rename_file.py", line 4, in rename_files
print os.listdir("Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨minstrelking⁩ ▸ ⁨Downloads⁩ ▸ ⁨prank⁩⁩")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Macintosh HD\xe2\x81\xa9 \xe2\x96\xb8 \xe2\x81\xa8Users\xe2\x81\xa9 \xe2\x96\xb8 \xe2\x81\xa8minstrelking\xe2\x81\xa9 \xe2\x96\xb8 \xe2\x81\xa8Downloads\xe2\x81\xa9 \xe2\x96\xb8 \xe2\x81\xa8prank\xe2\x81\xa9\xe2\x81\xa9'
```

I copied and pasted that file path directly from the "GET INFO" box that pops up when you right click the file. That folder "prank" has 30 image files, whose file names should be printing to the terminal. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "I tried replacing the small arrows ("▸") with forward slashes, then back slashes, and even a recommended combination of the two."—I would be _very_ surprised if those arrows worked. When you switched to forward slashes did you also remove the spaces around the arrows? Did you replace the HD with a leading forward slash? Something like `/Users⁩/minstrelking⁩/Downloads⁩/prank` should work.

Comment: @Chris OP says in the post, the 'file path directly from the "GET INFO" box'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the error trace, this is the actual directory Python is trying to find:

```
'Macintosh HD\xe2\x81\xa9 \xe2\x96\xb8 \xe2\x81\xa8Users\xe2\x81\xa9 \xe2\x96\xb8 \xe2\x81\xa8minstrelking\xe2\x81\xa9 \xe2\x96\xb8 \xe2\x81\xa8Downloads\xe2\x81\xa9 \xe2\x96\xb8 \xe2\x81\xa8prank\xe2\x81\xa9\xe2\x81\xa9'
```

which obviously is not a valid file directory.

Instead of copy+pasting the file path directly from the "GET INFO" box, use Terminal to go into the directory you want to search. Then type `pwd`. Use what that command prints out.

You claim you tried using slashes, but I'm almost certain you mistyped something somewhere, so the safest option will be using the output of `pwd`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. when I attempted to use slashes, this is how they were used.                                           list_files = os.listdir("⁨Users/⁨minstrelking⁩/⁨Downloads/⁨prank⁩")                                                                                               list_files = os.listdir("Macintosh HD/Users/⁨minstrelking⁩/⁨Downloads/⁨prank⁩⁩")

Comment: @minstrelking you forgot the initial slash, try: `"/⁨Users/⁨minstrelking⁩/⁨Downloads/⁨prank⁩"`

Comment: Thank you again. Here is my code, and the result.                   import os
def rename_files():
    # (1) get file names from a folder
    list_files = os.listdir("/Users/⁨minstrelking⁩/⁨Downloads/⁨prank⁩⁩")
    print (list_files)

rename_files()

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/minstrelking/Documents/rename_file.py", line 7, in <module>
    rename_files()
  File "/Users/minstrelking/Documents/rename_file.py", line 4, in rename_files
    list_files = os.listdir("/Users/⁨minstrelking⁩/⁨Downloads/⁨prank⁩⁩")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/\xe2\x81\xa8minstrelking\xe2\x81\xa9/\xe2\x81\xa8Downloads/\xe2\x81\xa8prank\xe2\x81\xa9\xe2\x81\xa9'
>>>

Comment: How would I go about using the method that involves the output pwd?

Comment: @minstrelking are you familiar with Terminal?

Comment: I am currently learning all that involves Python and Terminal, which is why I am having a bit of a difficult time.

Comment: @minstrelking in Terminal, enter the directory in question, and then type `pwd`.

Comment: like this?                                                                                    import os

def rename_files():
    os.listdir"/Users/⁨minstrelking⁩/⁨Downloads/⁨prank⁩⁩" pwd
    print list_files

Comment: @minstrelking no, on second thought forget the suggestion about `pwd`. Just use: `os.listdir("/Users/⁨minstrelking⁩/⁨Downloads/⁨prank⁩⁩")`. Don't forget the forward slash

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that. You have been a great help.